# Why Eclipse+PyDev cannot import the module termcolor?

Tags: eclipse, pydev, termcolor

Environments: Ubuntu v12.04 x64 + Eclipse Neon v4.6.0 x64 + PyDev v5.2.0 + Python v2.7.12 + termColor v1.1.0.

In the terminal of Ubuntu, Python command line can import termcolor and output colorful characters using commands like "print colored('hello','red')". It shows termcolor can work properly.

PyCharm community v2016.3 can import the module termcolor and work properly.

However, Eclipse+PyDev give the error "ImportError: No module named termcolor".
("from termcolor import colored" has been written.)

Can any expert give a solution to this problem? Thanks!

Edit: the PYTHONPATH in the interpreter is:

```
/home/usr/name/eclipseworkspace/pydevTest/src
/home/usr/name/eclipseworkspace/pydevTest/src
/home/usr/name/tools/eclipse-java-neon-R-linux-gtk-x86_64/plugins/org.python.pydev_5.2.0.201608171824/pysrc
/usr/local/lib/python2.7
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlrd-1.0.0-py2.7.egg
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlutils-2.0.0-py2.7.egg
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlwt-1.1.2-py2.7.egg
/usr/local/lib/python27.zip
```

and termcolor is:

```
<module 'termcolor' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/termcolor.pyc'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help in giving you a solution, please add to your module:

```
import sys
print('\n'.join(sorted(sys.path)))

import termcolor
print(termcolor)
```

Run it from PyDev and post the output here.

Then, just run:

```
import termcolor
print(termcolor)
```

from the console and also say what's the output you have.

Comment: It seems that the folder "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/" wasn't added in your interpreter configuration, so, please try adding it to the proper interpreter in the interpreter preferences and see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable help! I added the path to PyDev and the program worked properly!